# knapsack with different profits and weights

Tags: mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem

I have n items and m knapsacks. Each item has a profit and weight that depend on on which knapsack to put the item in. For example, for item 1, the profits are 9 and 10 for knapsacks m=1 and 2 respectively.Also, the weights of item 1 are 3 Kg and 4 Kg for knapsacks m=1 and 2 respectively.  what category of knapsacks problems does this problem belong to?. Is there an efficient method to solve such problem?.

I really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the multiple knapsack problem and is also related to the bin-packing problem. Some googling should get you some basic references. It's NP-hard but there are decent algorithms.

Comment: I looked at multiple knapsack problem "MKP". I think mine is different because in MKP, the profit of item n is the same for all knapsacks while in my problem the profit of item n depends on which knapsack to put in.

Comment: I see. I suspect that some MKP algorithms can be adapted to your variant, though you'd have to explore them in detail to figure that out.